Deprecate a specific action in ASP.NET Core Web API using Asp.Versioning.Mvc
In my ASP.NET Core Web API project, I implemented API versioning using the Asp.Versioning.Mvc package.
When deprecating a controller, its response header returns api-deprecated-versions: 1.0. It's working fine.
I would like to deprecate a specific action in my controller. Example: I have TestController and I have some action methods like Get, GetAll. I would like to deprecate the Get action.
How to implement this?

If you want to deprecated a specific action method in the controller, you could set it by using the attribute like below:
    [ApiVersion(1.0, Deprecated = true)]

More details, you could refer to below codes:
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion(1.0)]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("get")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        // Your action logic here
        return Ok("Get action");
    }

    [HttpGet("get-all")]
    public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
        // Your action logic here
        return Ok("GetAll action");
    }

    [HttpGet("get-deprecated")]
    [ApiVersion(1.0, Deprecated = true)]
    public IActionResult GetDeprecated()
    {
        // Your action logic here
        return Ok("This action is deprecated");
    }
}

Result:


this implementation does not return the response header as 'api-deprecated-versions: 1.0'. always return 'api-supported-versions'.

I don't understand why you want to put this header, if this api is deprecated, there is no need to put this header back.

@brando-zhang is mostly correct.
In short, it is not possible nor supported to deprecate part of an API. Although a single endpoint can represent an API, it usually does not. An API is typcially a collection of endpoints, which is naturally realized as a controller (but it doesn't have to be). In @brando-zhang's example, it is the Test API.
API version collation is performed at the logical API, not individual endpoints. There is no reliable way to collate endpoints otherwise. Endpoints for the same logical API could have completely different routes. This is even more troublesome for semantically equivalent endpoints; for example, test/{id} and test/{id:int} are semantically equivalent, but not the same. API Versioning does not consider that. It collates on the logical set (e.g. Test).
When you apply [ApiVersion] directly to an action/endpoint, you are essentially breaking that behavior. That individual endpoint is now a single API. While allowed, it's usually not what you want. The primarily use case for allowing this type of declaration is for version-neutral endpoints. A DELETE endpoint typically doesn't change between API versions, so you might declare a specific action/endpoint to be [ApiVersionNeutral].
The recommended course of action would be to create 1.1 version that doesn't include the action(s) you want deprecate and then mark 1.0 as deprecated. There doesn't have to be an implementation change in 1.1.
If you're willing to put forth the effort, you can probably achieve the result with the behavior that you want by implementing a custom IReportApiVersions service, but there is nothing provided out-of-the-box.
